# Get an available IP address from DHCP server via bash script?

Tags: python, bash, ip, dhcp

I have 3 servers A, B and C that already have IP addresses assigned by the DHCP server.

I wanted to request a fourth IP from the DHCP server that I can use as a floating IP between my service.

Is there a simple way to do this via python or bash/shell commands? Everything I've read is always talking about renewing the machines IP address not pooling another available IP.

Comment: My understanding is that a DHCP request must be bound to an interface one way or the other. But I would ask that on unix.stackoverflow.com or serverfault since it's not really a programming issue. Update: this might help http://superuser.com/questions/344733/getting-2-ip-addresses-on-one-network-card-using-dhcp

Comment: That is a valid point, I was thinking I might have to create the DHCP packet with a standard socket but was hoping there might be a library instead. The IP would be bound to an interface of the active server, the server would have 2 IP addresses associated with the same interface. I'll ask over on unix, I might just have to ping each IP and go from there.

Comment: @tgo Interesting thanks that explained a few things. I'll see if I can form my own pacet and modify the client ID to request a second IP.

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/225226/4667. Really belongs on http://serverfault.com/